# Is it a good practice to invalidate cookie/localStorage data when signing out?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, local-storage, single-page-application

I have SPA written in react and I store access token in localStorage and when I make API requests, I get it from local storage and send it as a header.

My questions:

1) Is it a good practice to just remove the data from localstorage when user signs out? Or should I ask the backend developer to add /signout endpoint?

2) Are there any security concerns which I should take into account  if I store access token in local storage?

Answer (score 0):

As answer to your question one. 
1) You should also invalidate the token / session in the backend as well depending on your api design.

2)
It's recommended to store tokens in bestcase in cookies because of security concerns, webstorage as a few possible security concerns.

https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage